# Show a $3\times3$ matrix is diagonalizable given certain traits.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let A be a $3\times3$ with $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\in\mathbb{R}$ and

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}2&a&b\\0&c&d\\0&e&f\end{bmatrix}$$

If $\lambda = 9$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and the characteristic equation is

$$f(t) = -t^3+gt^2+ht +18$$

show that A is diagonalizable.

From the characteristic polynomial I know $det(A) = 18\implies9\lambda_1\lambda_2=18\implies\lambda_1\lambda_2=2$. I figured that if we can show that $A$ has $3$ distinct eigenvalues then we can conclude that $A$ is diagonalizable however, I'm quite sure on how to progress from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** We can read off from the first column of $A$ that $2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.